# How can I fix Libreoffice after apt autoremove broke it?

Tags: 18.04, apt, package-management, libreoffice

I was installing R and RStudio on my pc because I need it for my course and while using the terminal to do that, the system suggested me to remove a bunch of files with autoremove. I though "the system knows better than me, right?" and I proceeded. Now I feel like Libreoffice is not working exactly as intended.

This is the result of checking file:///var/log/apt/history.log:

```
Start-Date: 2021-04-29  14:58:12
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: marco (1000)
Remove: firebird3.0-server-core:amd64 (3.0.2.32703.ds4-11ubuntu2), 
libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), liblibreoffice-java:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libhsqldb1.8.0-java:amd64 
(1.8.0.10+dfsg-10~18.04), libgpgmepp6:amd64 (1.10.0-1ubuntu2),
liblangtag-common:amd64 (0.6.2-1), libservlet3.1-java:amd64 (1:4.0.1-2~18.04), uno-libs-private:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1),
libreoffice-sdbc-postgresql:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libexttextcat-data:amd64 (3.4.5-1), libreoffice-sdbc-mysql:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:amd64 
(1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libjsp-api-java:amd64 (2.3.4-2~18.04), libreoffice-java-common:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libclucene-contribs1v5:amd64 (2.3.3.4+dfsg-1), libtommath1:amd64 (1.0.1-1), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libcommons-logging-java:amd64 (1.2-2), libexttextcat-2.0-0:amd64 (3.4.5-1), liblangtag1:amd64 (0.6.2-1), librdf0:amd64 (1.0.17-1.1), libyajl2:amd64 (2.1.0-2build1), libfbclient2:amd64 (3.0.2.32703.ds4-11ubuntu2), ure-java:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libreoffice-sdbc-firebird:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libpq5:amd64 (10.16-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), python3-uno:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libapache-pom-java:amd64 (18-1), libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), fonts-crosextra-carlito:amd64 (20130920-1), libreoffice-style-yaru:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libboost-iostreams1.65.1:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libcommons-parent-java:amd64 (43-1), 
libclucene-core1v5:amd64 (2.3.3.4+dfsg-1), libreoffice-style-colibre:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), ure:amd64 
(1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libreoffice-sdbc-hsqldb:amd64 
(1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libreoffice-common:amd64 
(1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), fonts-crosextra-caladea:amd64 
(20130214-2), mysql-common:amd64 (5.8+1.0.4), libwebsocket-api-java:amd64 
(1.1-1~18.04), libmhash2:amd64 (0.9.9.9-7), libboost-locale1.65.1:amd64 
(1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), libservlet-api-java:amd64 (4.0.1-2~18.04), 
libmysqlclient20:amd64 (5.7.33-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), libib-util:amd64 
(3.0.2.32703.ds4-11ubuntu2), libuno-cppu3:amd64 
(1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 
(2:102.12+LibO7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), libboost-filesystem1.65.1:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), 
libel-api-java:amd64 (3.0.0-2~18.04), linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-67:amd64 
(5.4.0-67.75~18.04.1), linux-hwe-5.4-headers-5.4.0-70:amd64 
(5.4.0-70.78~18.04.1), libuno-sal3:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), 
libraptor2-0:amd64 (2.0.14-1ubuntu0.18.04.1), librasqal3:amd64 
(0.9.32-1build1), libunoloader-java:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1), 
firebird3.0-common-doc:amd64 (3.0.2.32703.ds4-11ubuntu2), firebird3.0-common:amd64 (3.0.2.32703.ds4-11ubuntu2), 
libboost-date-time1.65.1:amd64 (1.65.1+dfsg-0ubuntu5), 
firebird3.0-utils:amd64 (3.0.2.32703.ds4-11ubuntu2), 
libmythes-1.2-0:amd64 (2:1.2.4-3), fonts-liberation2:amd64 (2.00.1-7~18.04.2), 
libreoffice-base-drivers:amd64 (1:7.1.2~rc2-0ubuntu0.18.04.1~lo1)
End-Date: 2021-04-29  15:00:03
```

How do I fix this? I need to restore just the parts related to Libreoffice, the rest can go.

And why did autoremove did something like that?!?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It depends on the method of RStudio installation. How did you installed it? Also place the output of `apt-cache policy r-base rstudio libreoffice` to the question body.

Comment: _RStudio has nothing to do with the issue_. It was after installing it that I noticed the message left by the system. Since I was using the terminal already - and trusting that it was a safe message - I decided to remove what I believed to be unnecessary packages. Now that I reinstalled Libreoffice + language packs, everything went back to normal. Everyone's happy! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Installing LibreOffice with GUI

Open Software Center, search for LibreOffice, and install it.

### Using CLI

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt install libreoffice
```

> And why did autoremove did something like that?!?

This is not supposed to happen. I have no idea why this happened. From the log, it seems that you were using the LibreOffice PPA, but that should not cause the issue either. I am using that PPA too, but autoremove never suggested to remove LibreOffice.

Comment: Thanks, man! You're the best, problem solved! :-)